# What is the cause that mercury has a large surface tension?

Tags: material-science, surface-tension

Mercury has a very large surface tension, but what causes this? Is that caused by the van der Waals forces because it has an high atomic number whereby there are a lot of electrons which makes mercury a kind op dipole because electrons are less binded to the core? Or are there other reasons? If not how does this metal compare to other heavy metals like gold?

And is this the same reason as why mercury is liquid at room temperature?

Answer (score 2):

What I knew and what  I found relevant is
  "**The high surface tension of mercury is due to intermetallic bonding. This bonding creates a strong "desire" for Hg atoms to interact with each other, versus their surroundings. In contrast, the surface tension of water is due to hydrogen bonding, a much weaker force that is easier to overcome." 
I found this answer on quora and it  seems good because Hg atoms share an intermetallic bond which is much stronger that the hydrogen bonds between water molecules."**
 This seems all right but what I found https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44898/why-is-mercurys-surface-tension-so-high-when-its-viscosity-is-low 
is closely related and it does raise a question on properties of mercury !